# Overflow when working with exponentials (Fortran)

Tags: fortran, numerical-methods

I'm having problems regarding the calculation of some exponentials. The problem is, i have a sum of exponentials that each one gives me overflow, so i didn't found a way to use logarithm to free myself of such big numbers.
For the code below, the program runs OK without overflow but I need to use bigger values of Eigenvalues, lets say, at least 300 times bigger. I couldn't find a way to work around the sum of exponentias using logarithm.

As you can see, the problem is not in the final result, but in the intermediate calculations.

Please let me know if this information is incomplete

```
program testing
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: q = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(10)
  integer, parameter :: qc = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(10)

  integer :: Ndim
  real (q)  :: Temperature
  real (q),allocatable  :: Eigenvalues (:),rho (:)
  real (q) :: Z
  integer :: i
  
Ndim=4

allocate (rho (Ndim),Eigenvalues(Ndim))
!Parameter Definition
Temperature=0.00000158
Eigenvalues(1)=-0.000893
Eigenvalues(2)=-0.000893
Eigenvalues(3)=-0.000788
Eigenvalues(4)=-0.000446
     Z = 0.;
     rho = 0.

     do i =1, Ndim
     Z = Z + exp ( - Eigenvalues (i)/(Temperature))
     write(*,*) Z
     enddo


     do i = 1, Ndim
     rho (i) = rho (i) + exp ( - Eigenvalues (i)/(Temperature) )/Z
     write(*,*) rho(i)
     enddo

end
```

Comment: Well, you're going to need to be clever with scaling.  `exp(x)` will overflow for x > 38 (single precision) or x > 708 (double precision).  These are sloppy limits, but good enough.  You can factor out a common value by `exp(x) = exp(a+b) = exp(a) * exp(b)`, and simply carry the knowledge that you've scaled the result.

Comment: Use the log-sum-exp algorithm? https://nhigham.com/2021/01/05/what-is-the-log-sum-exp-function/

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark My mistake, the real code is a subroutine and i just re-write it to be a minimal working example. I'm Fixing it right Now

Comment: You can go ~20 times higher with `real128` if your system supports it:
`use iso_fortran_env, only: q=>real128`

Answer (score 0):

For Boltzmann factors, rather than calculating `exp(-E/T)` explicitly, you will likely need to implement a `function boltzmann_factor(energy, temperature)` which checks the relative sizes of energy and temperature and calculates the output using the high-temperature or low-temperature Taylor expansions of `exp(-E/T)` where necessary.

Also note that since energy is relative you can subtract an arbitrary `E0` from all of your energies and obtain the same result, so modifying your code would give

```
do i =1, Ndim
  Z = Z + exp(-(Eigenvalues(i)-Eigenvalues(0)) / Temperature)
  write(*,*) Z
enddo


do i = 1, Ndim
  rho (i) = rho (i) + exp(-(Eigenvalues(i)-Eigenvalues(0))/Temperature)/Z
  write(*,*) rho(i)
enddo
```

this will be more stable, and more accurate.